# How to limit something that pulls me to the right when swimming?

Tags: technique, swimming

I have a problem to swim straight. When I swim, something pulls me to the right. This happens to me more when I swim breaststroke, and less when I swim crawl.

What could be the reason?

It think I have no scoliosis. Could this be a stronger left leg? I'm left-handed and left-legged.

How could I resolve that problem? What kind of exercises you would recommend?

Comment: Swimming is not a competitive sport?

Comment: The closing of swimming questions is currently being discussed at meta: http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/641/why-has-a-question-on-swimming-technique-been-closed-as-off-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swim in the lane next to a wall and have someone walk along and watch to see if there is an obvious discrepancy (strength, length of pull, imbalance, whatever) in your strokes.

Answer (score 3):

There must be an imbalance in your stroke. The most likely being a difference in your arm strokes, or in the degree that you are rolling side-to-side for each arm in freestyle (crawl). Have a look at the way your arms are pulling. Is your right elbow bent more that the left? Is your right arm pulling back as far as the left? Breaststroke kick is also hard to do symmetrically, most people kick or pull further with one leg than the other.
You can test if it's arms or legs first by swimming with a pool buoy and then kick board to isolate arms and legs and see which is turning you.
Good luck!